# changes are not commited in database but code runs and shows no error

Tags: vb.net, webforms

```
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-Q1UQIBI\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Admoresystem;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim query1 As String = "UPDATE OrderSheet SET OrderName=@ordername,Aux=@aux,Description=@description,Status=@status,Auxstatus=@auxstatus,TypeDeliveryDestination=@typedeliverydestination,TrackingnNumber=@trackingnumber,TurnOverDays=@turnoverdays where OrderID=@OrderID"

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query1, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderID", Val(txtOrderID.Text.Trim.ToString))

    '  Dim date2 As String = OrderDate.Text.ToString()
    'Dim startDateTimee As String = OrderDate.Text.Trim()
    '  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = OrderDate.Text

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ordername", txtOrderName.Text.Trim.ToString)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aux", txtAux.Text.Trim.ToString)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", txtDescription.Text.Trim.ToString)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", txtStatus.Text.Trim.ToString)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@auxstatus", txtAUXStatus.Text.Trim.ToString)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@typedeliverydestination", TypeDeliveryDestination.Text.Trim.ToString)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trackingnumber", txtTrackingNumber.Text.Trim.ToString)

    ' Dim est As String = EstimatedDeliveryDate.Text.ToString()
    '  cmd.Parameters.Add("@estdeliverydate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = EstimatedDeliveryDate.Text

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@turnoverdays", txtTurnOverDays.Text.Trim.ToString)
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    con.Dispose()

    Response.Redirect("DetailPage.aspx")
    'Controlsclear()
```

Comment: You're supposed to debug your code before posting a question here. If you have read up on the types and members you're using, which you should have, then you know that `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of records affected by the operation. If no exception is thrown, that number tells you whether data was saved (non-zero) or not (zero). If it is then it is and you're just wrong. If it's not then there are obviously no records in the database that match your `WHERE` clause so we can't tell you what it should be.

Comment: The way you've written your code suggest that you're not really thinking things through. You get the `Text` of a bunch of `TextBoxes` and, after trimming them, call `ToString`. What's the point of calling `ToString` on a `String`? It won;t hurt but the fact that you're doing something pointless means that you haven't thought about what you're doing. Also, why would you be calling `Val` to get the ID? Surely your `OrderID` is not type `Double`, so what use is `Val`? The best it will do is trim non-numeric characters but if that's required you should be telling the user, not ignoring them.

Comment: Finally - and I should have led with this - questions that are nothing but code are unacceptable. A question needs to be an actual question, with a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem and clear question that we can answer. It should be supported by code and images if required but they are additional, not all there is. The title should then be a summary, not the whole question.

Comment: In addition to everything else mentioned in the comments here which I 100% agree with, you might want to be a little careful when using AddWithValue.  It can do some implicit type casting on you and cause unexpected results

Comment: hi everyone, I have write simple query to update data. these changes like tostring, val and trim are used by my senior.On the other hand delete query runs and delete the same value.

Comment: i had used simple query to update.these changes like val,trim and tostring are written by my senior.jmcilhinney ,if any parsing error accour it must showed but there is no error while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Tell your senior to sit up and take notice. His code has been criticized on Stack Overflow by several of his peers.

If there is an error in the code the connection and command will never be closed and disposed. Using...End Using blocks were added for just this reason.

Separate your user interface code from your data access code. They should be completely independent. When you must have several parameters to pass to the data base code, it is better to make a class, set the parameters and pass a single object.

You will need to check your database for the correct datatypes for the parameters and correct the code accordingly.

Don't use `AddWithValue` with SQL Server. http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

```
Private Function UpdateOrders(OrderToUpdate As Order) As Integer
    Dim query1 As String = "UPDATE OrderSheet SET OrderName=@ordername,Aux=@aux,Description=@description,Status=@status,Auxstatus=@auxstatus,TypeDeliveryDestination=@typedeliverydestination,TrackingnNumber=@trackingnumber,TurnOverDays=@turnoverdays where OrderID=@OrderID"
    Dim recordsUpdated As Integer
    Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-Q1UQIBI\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Admoresystem;Integrated Security=True"),
            cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query1, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrderID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OrderToUpdate.ID
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ordername", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = OrderToUpdate.Name
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@aux", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = OrderToUpdate.Aux
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = OrderToUpdate.Description
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = OrderToUpdate.Status
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@auxstatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = OrderToUpdate.AuxStatus
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@typedeliverydestination", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = OrderToUpdate.DelDestType
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@trackingnumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OrderToUpdate.TrackNum
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@turnoverdays", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OrderToUpdate.TurnOverDays
        con.Open()
        recordsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    Return recordsUpdated
End Function

Public Class Order
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Aux As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property Status As String
    Public Property AuxStatus As String
    Public Property DelDestType As String
    Public Property TrackNum As Integer
    Public Property TurnOverDays As Integer
End Class


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ord As New Order
    Dim id As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(txtOrderId.Text, id) Then
        ord.ID = id
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid Id")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ord.Name = txtOrderName.Text.Trim
    ord.Aux = txtAux.Text.Trim
    ord.Description = txtDescription.Text.Trim
    ord.Status = txtStatus.Text.Trim
    ord.AuxStatus = txtAUXStatus.Text.Trim
    ord.DelDestType = TypeDeliveryDestination.Text.Trim
    Dim trackingNum As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(txtTrackingNumber.Text.Trim, trackingNum) Then
        ord.TrackNum = trackingNum
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid tracking number")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim days As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(txtTurnOverDays.Text.Trim, days) Then
        ord.TurnOverDays = days
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid turn over days")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim RecordsUpdated As Integer
    Try
        RecordsUpdated = UpdateOrders(ord)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Update Failed")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    MessageBox.Show($"{RecordsUpdated} record was succesfully updated.")
End Sub
```

Not a `.ToString()` in sight.

Comment: I got it.The problem was with postback function.I had not used the postback function that is why it was not commiting changes.Now its fine and working properly